# Native OS X apps in JS?

Tags: javascript, macos, cocoa, cross-platform

I would like to write an application in JavsScript that runs natively on OS X.  It would be a bonus if it could be used for Windows apps as well, however I am primarily interested in the OS X / Cocoa tie in initially.

I was entertaining the possibility of writing all of the business logic in JS and then the primary UI components with Cocoa and .NET respectively, but I got to thinking that it would be nice if there were something already in place that would facilitate such a workflow without having to support a few different codebases.

After researching this a bit, I obviously became overwhelmed with the solutions that seem to exist for iOS development, however hitherto I've found nothing that really seems to also work on OS X.  Are there any solutions that I may be overlooking?  If not, what might be the recommended path for basing most business logic in a JavaScript app and interfacing with that for the native UI components?

Comment: I guess you could make a simple app that is just a fullscreen web browser without an address bar or something, then download the HTML and CSS and JS in your app then automatically set the web browser to go to the main HTML page on startup

Comment: crx web apps for chrome, manifests for firefox, and adobe AIR are all cross-platform dev environments using JS that will work on mac and pc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is becoming a hot topic.  I suggest you read [this article](http://www.steamclock.com/blog/2013/05/apple-objective-c-javascript-bridge/) about a JavaScript Objective-C bridge for OS 10.9.  Also, check out this [code sample from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/JavaScriptCoreHeadstart/Introduction/Intro.html) in which the application controller is simply responsible for communicating between objects and JavaScript is really driving everything.  The sample is called JavaScriptCoreHeadstart and Apple describes it as follows:

> JavaScriptCore is a new system framework available in Mac OS X 10.5 that allows applications to run 
>   JavaScripts. This sample shows one way to use JavaScriptCore for providing user configurable features 
>   in a Cocoa application. Here, a number of JavaScript objects are defined that represent various parts 
>   of the application and the application's controller is really just a thin shell that calls 
>   JavaScripts that decide how the application will operate in response to Interface Builder action 
>   method calls and WebKit delegate callbacks. The JavaScripts themselves control the application 
>   through the objects that represent different parts of the application.

Answer (score 2):

There is [NodObjC](https://github.com/TooTallNate/NodObjC) that should allow you to write Cocoa applications for NodeJS.

Comment: It's great that this project exists. My 2c states that the api is a bit too 'bridge like', meaning that the api isn't very Javascript-ish acting more in a function-dispatch arrangement.